# NSKeyedArchiver does not archive my Codable class

Tags: ios, swift4, nskeyedarchiver, codable

Here is my Codable class:

```
class SensorOutput: Codable {

    var timeStamp: Date?

    var gyroX: Double?
    var gyroY: Double?
    var gyroZ: Double?

    var accX: Double?
    var accY: Double?
    var accZ: Double?

    var magX: Double?
    var magY: Double?
    var magZ: Double?

    init() {}
}
```

Here I try to write and read the object of that class to file:

```
    let myData = SensorOutput()
    myData.timeStamp = Date()
    myData.gyroX = 0.0
    myData.gyroY = 0.0
    myData.gyroZ = 0.0
    myData.accX = 0.0
    myData.accY = 0.0
    myData.accZ = 0.0
    myData.magX = 0.0
    myData.magY = 0.0
    myData.magZ = 0.0

    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myData, toFile: filePath)

    if let Data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? SensorOutput {
        print (Data)
    }
```

This gives an error during the process of archiving:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PnwI.png)

PS: filePath I receiving in such way:

```
var filePath: String {
    //1 - manager lets you examine contents of a files and folders in your app; creates a directory to where we are saving it
    let manager = FileManager.default
    //2 - this returns an array of urls from our documentDirectory and we take the first path
    let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    print("this is the url path in the documentDirectory \(String(describing: url))")
    //3 - creates a new path component and creates a new file called "Data" which is where we will store our Data array.
    return (url!.appendingPathComponent("Data").path)
}
```

Reading/writing works with Int or Double and with other supported types, but not with my type. What’s wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although @matt's answer contains the essential information to solve your problem, it might not be obvious how to apply that information if you're new to Swift and iOS programming.

You tried using `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(_:toFile:)`, which is a class method, so you didn't have to create an instance of `NSKeyedArchiver`. Since `encodeEncodable(_:forKey:)` is an instance method, not a class method, you need to create an instance of `NSKeyedArchiver` to use it. You also need to create an `NSMutableData` for the archiver to append bytes to, and you have to call `finishEncoding` after encoding your object.

```
    let sensorOutput = SensorOutput()
    sensorOutput.timeStamp = Date()

    let mutableData = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: mutableData)
    try! archiver.encodeEncodable(sensorOutput, forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey)
    archiver.finishEncoding()

    // You can now write mutableData to a file or send it to your server
    // or whatever.
```

Similarly, you tried using `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile:)`, which is a class method, but you need to use `decodeDecodable(_:forKey:)` or `decodeTopLevelDecodable(_:forKey:)`, which are instance methods. So you need to read in the archive data and use it to make an instance of `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

```
// Read in the data from a file or your server or whatever.
// I'll just make an immutable copy of the archived data for this example.
let data = mutableData.copy() as! Data

let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
do {
    if let sensorOutputCopy = try unarchiver.decodeTopLevelDecodable(SensorOutput.self, forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) {
        print("deserialized sensor output: \(sensorOutputCopy)")
    }
} catch {
    print("unarchiving failure: \(error)")
}
```

(I prefer the `decodeTopLevelDecodable` method instead of `decodeDecodable` because it throws a Swift error instead of crashing if the archive is corrupt.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, all works. But how to get URL of NSMutableData or how to send the saved file from Apple Watch to iPhone using transferFile(_:metadata:) ?

Comment: You can write the `NSMutableData` to a file using one of its `write(toFile:atomically:)`, `write(toFile:options:)`, `write(to:atomically:)`, or `write(to:options:)` methods. (It inherits these methods from `NSData`).

Answer (score 9):

The error message is telling you that `SensorOutput` needs to derive from NSObject.

However, the root problem is that you are using NSKeyedArchiver wrong. You are calling `archiveRootObject`, acting as if this type adopted NSCoding. It doesn't. It adopts Codable. If you are going to use the fact that this type is Codable, you call NSKeyedArchiver `encodeEncodable(_:forKey:)` to encode and NSKeyedUnarchiver `decodeDecodable(_:forKey:)` to decode.

Answer (score 0):

You were using it the wrong way. It adopts `Codable` protocol not `NSCoding` one. *(As @matt pointed out)*.

You could solve it like that:

```
let myData = SensorOutput()
let data = try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(myData)
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data)
```